# Difference between Internal and external traffic in production phase

Tags: google-analytics

If you have a asp.net mvc project and you have the Google's tracking code and you want to use it for production phase and not for development phase.

1. What settings in Google analytics should it be? Should I apply my ip-number for internal or external traffic in filter?
2. What is the difference betwee n internal and external traffic from Google Analytics?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics does not differentiate between "internal" and "external" traffic - these are labels commonly used in filters, but what they mean is up to you.

If you use a filter to exclude hits with your IP then the view will remove your own traffic.

If you use a filter to include hits with your IP then Google Analytics will delete all data except visits with that IP (so you want to be careful with include filters and always keep an unfiltered view).

If you use IP anonymization then filtering out a single IP will not work at all (since the last octet of an IP4 ip address will be set to "0"), you would have to exclude a whole block.

Comment: "If you use a filter to exclude hits with your IP then the view will remove your own traffic." When the website is in production phase and when I use my own computer then I cannot se my own data traffic?

Comment: You can see it being sent in the browser console or via debugging software, but it will not show up in the interface.

Comment: Do you have tutorial some something similiar. It is easier to understand.

Comment: I have tried this code "@if (!HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)" but it doesn't work (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160005/prevent-google-analytics-from-gathering-data-in-development-environment-asp-net)